# Nginx multiple sites enable, different roots

Tags: laravel, nginx, config

I have two configs with two different roots:

Config One:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name cert-portal;

    root /var/www/cert-portal/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Config two

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mediawiki;

    root /var/www/mediawiki;

    index  index.php;

    client_max_body_size 5m;
    client_body_timeout 60;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1&$args;
    }

    location ^~ /maintenance/ {
        return 403;
    }

     location /rest.php {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /rest.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;


    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /_.gif {
        expires max;
        empty_gif;
    }

    location ^~ /cache/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /dumps {
        root /var/www/mediawiki/local;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

How can I reach both?
At the moment when I open my website I get only config one (/var/www/cert-portal/public).

But I like to have
http://example.com/cert-portal shows /var/www/cert-portal/public
http://example.com/wiki shows /var/www/mediawiki

Comment: You have 2 different server names that cannot both be `example.com`. You should handle it with 2 different locations.

Comment: If you are not setting reverse proxy, two sites won't work in same port ever, nginx will only passed request into the first site that matches condition. You can set site two use another port like 8080 or setting two sites root as sub path.

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
server {
  location / {
    root /var/www/cert-portal/public;
  }

  location /wiki(.*) {
    root /var/www/mediawiki;
  }
}
```

Comment: no this also dose not work :(

Comment: The second location is clearly wrong. You should add `~` if you want to use regex.